# Does a mysqli_commit failure automatically rollback?

Tags: php, mysqli, commit, rollback

I have some questions about how this code from the PHP manual operates. I see other examples that throw exceptions (usually object oriented code) or use flags to track failures of each individual query.

My question is why would you have to flag errors and test for the flag before deciding to commit or rollback. Looking at the example below it appears that if the commit does not work, none of the queries would be committed anyway.

I also noticed they just simply exit on failure of the commit. Does that automatically roll back everything?

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "test");

/* check connection */
if (!$link) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* set autocommit to off */
mysqli_autocommit($link, FALSE);

mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TABLE Language LIKE CountryLanguage");

/* Insert some values */
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO Language VALUES ('DEU', 'Bavarian', 'F',     11.2)");
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO Language VALUES ('DEU', 'Swabian', 'F', 9.4)");

/* commit transaction */
if (!mysqli_commit($link)) {
    print("Transaction commit failed\n");
    exit();
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Where do you start your transaction?

Comment: @Sven it can be clearly seen in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Looking at the example below it appears that if the commit does not work, none of the queries would be committed anyway.

Right.

But the point is that *an error could occur not only with commit.* But - even more likely - *with one of the queries executed.* So you need to check not only the commit result, but also every query's result and abort the whole operation.

So, your question should read as

> Does a mysqli failure automatically rollback?

And the answer is "yes and no".
By default it won't.
But if you manage to abort your script on a query failure, the link will be closed and the transaction will be rolled back automatically. The code below converts mysql errors in PHP fatal errors which will automatically do a rollback if one of the queries failed.

```
<?php
/* set the proper error reporting mode */
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "test");

/* set autocommit to off */
mysqli_autocommit($link, FALSE);

/* Run your queries */
mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TABLE Language LIKE CountryLanguage");
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO Language VALUES ('DEU', 'Bavarian', 'F',     11.2)");
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO Language VALUES ('DEU', 'Swabian', 'F', 9.4)");

/* commit transaction */
mysqli_commit($link);

/* this is the last line, NO other code is needed */
```

Comment: Perfect! That's just what I needed!